# Tensorflow saved models get bigger when running cross-validation

Tags: tensorflow

What's the correct way to run cross-validation on Tensorflow?
Below are my code snippets:

```
class TextCNN:
  ...
  def train(self):
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      ...
      # training loop
      ...
      # training finished
      path = saver.save(sess, "{:s}/model.{:d}".format(self.checkpoint_dir, self.test_fold))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  for i in range(CV_SIZE):
    cnn = TextCNN(i)
    cnn.train()
```

The saved model size for fold 0 is around 2M. But for fold 1 around 4M, fold 2 around 6M, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the `TextCNN` constructor and `train()` method are adding nodes to the default graph ([`tf.get_default_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#get_default_graph)) and the saved model includes all previous graphs, so it is "accidentally quadratic" and growing with each iteration of the `__main__` loop.

The solution is easy, fortunately. Just rewrite your main loop as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  for i in range(CV_SIZE):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():  # Performs training in a new, empty graph.
      cnn = TextCNN(i)
      cnn.train()
```

This will create a new, empty graph for each iteration of the loop. Therefore the saved model will not contain the nodes (and variables) from the previous iteration, and the model size should remain constant.

Note that, if possible, you should try to reuse the same graph for all iterations. However, I realize that this might not be possible if the structure of the graph changes from one iteration to the next.